# How do I dynamically create a graphene Object? For example, I want to at run time add fields and resolvers based off of a configuration file

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic, reflection, graphene-python

I want to be able to create a GraphQL Server dynamically from a given configuration file. So for example, my configuration file will include what fields should exist, and some of the fields will have a flag indicating them as the primary key or secondary key which will map to them getting a resolver. 
How would I achieve dynamically creating a graphene object type?

I tried taking graphene's example code and adding fields to it. But it won't accept them. I tried diving into the meta data and updating some options, but that hasn't panned out either.

```py
class User(graphene.ObjectType):
    id = graphene.ID()
    name = graphene.String()


class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    me = graphene.Field(User)

    def resolve_me(self, info):
        return info.context["user"]

schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)
query = """
    query something{
      me {
        name
        temp
      }
    }
"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    userobj = User
    print(dir(userobj._meta.fields))
    setattr(userobj,"temp", graphene.String())
    print((userobj._meta.fields))

    userobj._meta.fields.update({"temp": graphene.String()})
    print(userobj._meta.fields)

    print((userobj._meta.fields))
    result = schema.execute(query, context={"user": userobj(id="X", name="Console", temp="hey")})
    print(result.data)
    print(result.data["me"])
```

Currently I get None with this attempt. Taking out the portion where I update _meta.fields, I get 'temp isn't a valid argument' for creating a userobj. 'temp' is an invalid keyword argument for User

Answer (score 1):

Currently looking into solutions for the same problem. There is a possible [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50559580/creating-dynamic-schema-on-runtime-graphene)

Answer (score 0):

So, the issue is that the graphene.ObjectType is not a regular Python class. It has a special [metaclass](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/metaclasses.html) that you can see implemented [here](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/blob/master/graphene/utils/subclass_with_meta.py). At the moment Python takes care of the inheritance process (when the class itself is initalized), graphene does some operations to register the type. I didn't find a way to change types after the inheritance happens. However, if you just want to generate the schema out of a predefined boilerplate (like me) or some other source, you can do something like this. I first define a handy inherit method:

```
def inherit_from(Child, Parent, persist_meta=False):
    """Return a class that is equivalent to Child(Parent) including Parent bases."""
    PersistMeta = copy(Child.Meta) if hasattr(Child, 'Meta') else None

    if persist_meta:
        Child.Meta = PersistMeta

    # Prepare bases
    child_bases = inspect.getmro(Child)
    parent_bases = inspect.getmro(Parent)
    bases = tuple([item for item in parent_bases if item not in child_bases]) + child_bases

    # Construct the new return type
    try:
        Child = type(Child.__name__, bases, Child.__dict__.copy())
    except AttributeError as e:
        if str(e) == 'Meta':
            raise AttributeError('Attribute Error in graphene library. Try setting persist_meta=True in the inherit_from method call.')
        raise e

    if persist_meta:
        Child.Meta = PersistMeta

    return Child
```

Now the key is to perform the inheritance when the type's class is not about to change anymore.

```
def context_resolver_factory(attr):
    """Create a simple resolver method with default return value None."""

    def resolver(obj, info):
        return info.context.get(attr, None)

    return resolver


class User:
    id = graphene.ID()
    name = graphene.String(resolver=lambda user, info: user.name)


class Query: pass
    me = graphene.Field(User)

    def resolve_me(self, info):
        return info.context["user"]


inherit_from(User, graphene.ObjectType)  # no changes to User class are possible after this line

# method 1: sometimes it's really neat and clean to include a resolver in the field definition
setattr(Query, 'user', graphene.User(resolver=context_resolver_factory('user'))
# or even use lambda if a factory is still overkill
setattr(Query, 'user', graphene.User(resolver=lambda query, info: info.context["user"]))


# method 2: if you want to set the resolver separately, you can do it this way
setattr(Query, 'user', graphene.User())
setattr(Query, 'resolve_user', context_resolver_factory('user'))

# any changes to `Query.Meta` can be done here too

inherit_from(Query, graphene.ObjectType)  # no changes to Query class are possible after this line

schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)
```

Where I got with my little library was generating everything from a boilerplate class like this (I think you're after something similar):

```
@register_type('Product')
class ProductType:
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
        related_fields = {
            NestedField('tags', TagType),
            NestedField('related_products', 'self'),
        }
        lookups = {
            'id': graphene.ID(),
            'name': graphene.String(description="Name"),
            'ean': graphene.String(),
            'brand': graphene.String()
        }
        filters = {
            'ids': IDFilter,
            'django_filter': DjangoFilter,
            'pagination': PaginationFilter,
            'search_name': ProductMLNSearchFilter
        }
```

Biggest challenge were the NestedFields and figuring out automatic Django ORM query select/prefetch when a request comes in, but I won't go into detail unless that's something relevant.